# Is there any technical/conceptual reason boost::circular_buffer does not support move symantics?

Tags: c++, boost, move, circular-buffer

I want to fill a boost::circular_buffer with unique_ptrs but i don't find any "emplace" function or any && arguments in any functions in the public interface. Is there any particular reason circular_buffer can't support move that I'm missing?

Comment: I think its just not implemented

Comment: File a feature request at http://svn.boost.org

Comment: thanks Marschall, I filed a ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7888 this is now implemented in Boost.  It seems the original implementation was in 1.55, with some fixes for compiler warnings in 1.57.

There is, however, still no support for `emplace()`, `emplace_front()`, or `emplace_back()` as of Boost 1.63.  For that effort, see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9299.